# What does "Autoscale could not be enabled for [cloudservice]" in Azure Portal mean?

Tags: azure, autoscaling

When I login to "Windows Azure Management Portal" I get the following warning in the notification tray:

> Autoscale could not be enabled for [cloudserivce]"

When I click I'm redirected to the Scale tab for the specified cloud service, with no more info.

The cloud service is configured to autoscale based on CPU (60-80 target) and between 2-10 instances.

Everything looks OK to me, so why do I get this warning, and what does it mean?

[image]

Comment: Just a thought, have you got enough metrics being collected and saved in an appropriate place for AutoScale to work? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680945(v=pandp.50).aspx#sec25

Comment: I've just added an image. As you can see there are CPU metrics.

Comment: Send email to [MyName].[MyLastName]@microsoft.com with details about your cloud service name. I will have a look in logs.

Comment: Thanks Ilya... I've send a mail to Tabrez, who also asked for details ;-) Great service!

Comment: I have the same exact issue.  @Ilya, let me know if I can help supply data too. (screenshot, cloud service name, etc)

Comment: Hi @MatthewT, please submit email with details to me and Tabrez. We will take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to Ilya and Tabrez we found the problem.

It turned out that the error message was misleading, and that it actually meant "auto-scale job failed to perform scale action". According to Ilya this is fixed (but not deployed)

I've tried to scale manually and got the following error:

> The certificate with thumbprint XXXXXXXXXXXXX was not found.

A few days ago I've changed the SSL certificate thumbprint directly on the configuration tab of the Cloud Service, and then deleted the old certificate. This was reflected correct on our website. But we was also using this certificate for Remote Desktop. The running instances already had the old certificate installed, but Auto Scale was not able to install this certificate on new instances.

Thanks to Ilya and Tabrez for helping... great support.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely you've exceeded the quota for roles with autoscale enabled. If you share your subscription and deployment IDs with me (tabrezm[at]microsoft[dot]com), we can take a look. We're working on making the error messages exposed in the portal better for this.

Comment: Thanks... I'v send you a mail with details :-)